# Continuous boundary of a convex set

Tags: convex-analysis

Is the boundary of a compact convex set in Rn continuous? Seems like the answer should obviously be yes, but I cannot find any such result in the literature. Can somebody provide a reference (or a proof)? Thanks.

Comment: The boundary of any set is a set and as such cannot be continuous. What intuitive property do you have in mind?

Comment: I'd guess OP intended connected or path-connected rather than continuous?

Comment: Yes, exactly, I meant "connected" rather than continuous.

Comment: Please add this clarification to your question (there is an [edit](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/287960/edit) link at the bottom left of your question). You can get a nice $\Bbb R^n$ by writing `$\Bbb R^n$`

Answer (score 5):

Let $A\subset \mathbb R^n$ be compact and convex and assume that it is not contained in any $(n-1)$-dimensional affine subspace.

We may assume wlog, that $S^{n-1}\subset A$.
The the projection from the origin induces a bijection $S^{n-1}\to \partial A$. One readily checks that this is in fact a homeomorphism and makes $\partial A$ a manifold. Note that for $n=1$ this means that $\partial A$ is not connected.