# Connected set imply continuous boundary

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Is it true that a connected and bounded set of $\mathbb{R}^2$ has a boundary that can be parametrized by a continuous mapping?

Comment: Did you mean "convex"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Continuous boundary of a convex set](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287960/continuous-boundary-of-a-convex-set)

Comment: No. I mean conex

Comment: @Student: "conex" does not mean anything. Maybe "connected"?

Comment: Yes, I mean connected. Sorry about that stupid mistake of mine. In my language connected=conex.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true in general. For a simple counterexample, consider the following set in $\mathbb{R}^2$: $\mathcal{S} = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 1 \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 4\}$. $\mathcal{S}$ is just an annulus centered at the origin whose larger radius is $2$ and whose smaller radius is $1$.

- It is bounded because it is, by construction, entirely contained in the disk $\Omega = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 + y^2 \leq 4\}$.
- Not only is it connected, it is even path connected. Check this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306461/an-annulus-in-mathbb-r2-is-path-connected) out for a simple proof of this.
- However, its boundary $\delta \mathcal{S}$ is *not* connected since it comprises of two disjoint circles centered at the origin with radii $2$ and $1$ respectively.

The last point means that any function $f : [0,1] \to \delta \mathcal{S}$ whose image is the whole of $\delta \mathcal{S}$ cannot be continuous since the interval $[0,1] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is connected while our image is not. This follows from the fact that [the continuous image of a connected space must be connected](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Image_of_Connected_Space_is_Connected).

So you cannot have a continuous parameterization of the boundary of our annulus $\mathcal{S}$ despite the fact that it is both bounded and connected.